# Is the satyr's Mirthful Leaps trait affected by jump multipliers?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, racial-traits

In the new sourcebook *Mythic Odysseys of Theros* (p. 25), the new [Satyr](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/satyr) race has the [Mirthful Leaps trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/satyr#SatyrTraits):

> Whenever you make a long or high jump, you can roll a d8 and add the number rolled to the number of feet you cover, even when making a standing jump. This extra distance costs movement as normal.

If you have a multiplier on jump distance, such as that provided by the [*Boots of Striding and Springing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/boots-of-striding-and-springing)...

> In addition, you can jump three times the normal distance, though you can't jump farther than your remaining movement would allow.

... would the +1d8 feet from Mirthful Leaps be multiplied by 3 as well?

Comment: Related: [Understanding the mechanics of a satyr's Mirthful Leaps trait](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/178008/33569)

Comment: Also tangentially related: [Can animal-like playable races wear shoes/boots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119716/can-animal-like-playable-races-wear-shoes-boots)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Boots of Striding and Springing triple your unmodified jump distance.

I would make the argument that when [Boots of Striding and Springing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/boots-of-striding-and-springing) says

> you can jump three times the **normal** distance,

this is referring to your unmodified (normal) jump distance, to which you may then add modifiers.

I believe if the Boots multiplied the modifiers as well, it would read similar to the [*Jump*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/jump) spell:

> the creature's jump distance is tripled

*Jump* triples your jump distance for its duration, modifiers included; if it was intended to triple your distance without first accounting for modifiers it would read as the Boots do, using the word "normal".