# How does the Harengon's Rabbit Hop racial trait interact with the Jump spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, racial-traits

If my level 2 ranger casts the *Jump* spell on our harengon monk, does his jump distance *from his Rabbit hop racial ability* also tripled?

> **Rabbit Hop.** As a bonus action, you can jump a number of feet equal to five times your proficiency bonus, without provoking opportunity attacks. You can use this trait only if your speed is greater than 0. You can use it a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

And here is the *Jump* spell:

> You touch a creature. The creature's jump distance is tripled until the spell ends.

RAF it obviously works, because a rabbit jumping crazy distances is hilarious, but I'm interested if it works RAW or RAI.

Comment: Related: [Is the satyr's Mirthful Leaps trait affected by jump multipliers?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169952)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It's at least Rules As Intended

The [Sage Advice: Creature Evolutions](https://dnd.wizards.com/sage-advice/creature-evolutions) column from October 4, 2021 clarified that the *jump* spell triples the distance a Harengon can jump with its Rabbit Hop feature:

> **Does the *jump* spell benefit Rabbit Hop?**
>
> Yes, the *jump* spell can affect the jump distance of Rabbit Hop. If you cast that spell on a harengon, enjoy the magnificent leaps!

Moreover, Rabbit Hop doesn't expend movement, so in contrast to a high or long jump, you're not limited in the range you can hop even if it exceeds your movement speed:

> **When a harengon uses Rabbit Hop, does the trait’s jump expend movement?**
>
> The Rabbit Hop trait lets a harengon jump as a bonus action, and that jump doesn’t consume any of the harengon’s normal movement. That fact is why the trait has a limited number of uses between long rests. If you compare the wording of Rabbit Hop to the wording of the long and high jump rules in the *Player’s Handbook*, you’ll see that those rules explicitly expend movement, whereas Rabbit Hop doesn’t.

Answer (score 14):

#### This should work.

When the [*jump*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/jump) spell says "jump distance", it is most obviously referring to the [rules for long jumps](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Jumping) in chapter 8 of the *Player's Handbook*:

> ##### Jumping
>
> Your Strength determines how far you can jump.
>
> **Long Jump.** When you make a long jump, you cover a number of feet up to your Strength score if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing long jump, you can leap only half that distance. Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement.

This is how you determine your "jump distance", and this is what *jump* was originally referring to. Now, **Rabbit Hop** provides a completely different jumping mechanic, *but it does provide a method of calculating a "jump distance"*:

> you can jump a number of feet equal to five times your proficiency bonus

So while this isn't the "jump distance" the *jump* spell was originally referring to, as **Rabbit Hop** was published some seven years after the *jump spell*, it is still a "jump distance" - it tells you how far you can jump.

It is important to note that while conventional jumping expends your available movement, using **Rabbit Hop** *does not use your available movement*, and can even be used if you have no remaining movement this turn (and your speed is not 0).

Comment: In revising my answer, agreeing that the *specific beats general* rule does not apply here, I also realised that there is some inconsistency in yours. I would disagree that "jump distance" *obviously* refers to the rules for long jumps. Indeed, there is no mentioning in the PHB of the specific term "jump distance". Instead, a letter reading of the PHB text would suggest that the **jump** spell affects *any* jump made by the character which has a distance.

Comment: @FerventHippo Any jump made by the character follows the rules for jumping.

Answer (score 0):

#### This shouldn't work.

As noted by [Thomas Markov](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/193577/32750), When the [*jump*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/jump) spell says "jump distance", it refers to the [rules for long jumps](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Jumping) in chapter 8 of the *Player's Handbook* (emphasis mine):

> ##### Jumping
>
> Your Strength determines how far you can jump.
>
> **Long Jump.** When you make a long jump, you cover a number of feet up to your Strength score if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing long jump, you can leap only half that distance. *Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement*.

This "jump distance" is evidently connected to the movement on a character's turn, as the emphasised sentence specifies that this kind of jump "costs a foot of movement". Now, **Rabbit Hop** does not interact with movement at all (again, emphasis mine):

> *As a bonus action*, you can jump a number of feet equal to five times your proficiency bonus

As this is done as a bonus action, there is no relationship to the possible jump distance which expends movement. The possible jump distance in this case is exactly what is specified by the ability, i.e. "equal to five times your proficiency bonus".

<sub>*Disclaimer: all things considered, I think I'd still allow this on my table based on the rule of cool....*</sub>

Comment: The usual jump distance seems just as specific: a number of feet up to your strength score. The *specific beats general rule* is for where one rule *specifically* contradicts another. That’s not what we have here. Here we just have two features that tell you how far you can jump, and a spell that triples how far you can jump.

Comment: That looks better by me, undeleted. And in future, raising a flag is usually a better way to get hold of a mod, so you aren't relying on one of us to stumble back on it. :)

Comment: I did flag it but then unflagged because I realised my logic doesn't really hold... But i'll let the downvotes decide :) Thanks for letting me know about the previous issues.